# Break double into chars using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting

Can I cast a pointer to a double as type `char *`, then use that pointer to break the double into bytes?

Here's example code:

```
double data;
double *dblPoint = &data;
unsigned char *bytePoint = (unsigned char *)dblPoint;
unsigned char byteArray[sizeof (double)];
unsigned int i;

for(i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++) {
    byteArray[i] = *(bytePoint + i);
}
```

`byteArray` is then transmitted via UART to another computer and reconstructed (`bytesReceived` contains the incoming data):

```
unsigned char bytesReceived[sizeof (double)];

double reconstData;
double *newDblPoint;
unsigned int i;

newDblPoint = bytesReceived;
reconstData = *dblPoint;
```

So, after all that, would `data == reconstData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example can be simplified to:

```
double data;
unsigned char bytesReceived[sizeof double];
memcpy ( bytesReceived, &data, sizeof data);
```

Your second example is not valid: the buffer

```
unsigned char bytesReceived[sizeof double];
```

Is not necessarily aligned on a "double" boundary, so that the cast

```
newDblPoint = bytesReceived;
reconstData = *dblPoint;
```

will attempt to dereference an unaligned pointer.

Comment: How would I go about making sure it is properly aligned?

Comment: The cleanest way is using an union. But you don't need the pointer-casting; memcpy is good enough.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can basically do that. One issue to watch out for is that if the two machines don't have the same endianness, then you will need to reverse the byte ordering on one side.

Answer (score 1):

See 6.2.6.1/4 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Basically, it says copying any object to an array of `unsigned char` is legal and gets its *object representation*.

If the object representation of doubles is the same between the 2 machines, you'll get the same value on the 2nd machine as the one you started off with on the 1st.

I'd use `memcpy` rather than the loop

```
memcpy(byteArray, &data, sizeof data);
```